# Regex to match exact number in string without lookahead or lookbehind

Tags: mysql, regex, mysql-5.7

Let's say I'm looking for a specific number in string with newlines:
1\n2\n4\n5\n7\n8\n9\n12\n13

Lookahead and lookbehind works perfectly with something like:

```
(?<![0-9])12(?![0-9])
```

See [Regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/V9TVJp/1).

However, I need a workaround for the MySQL `REGEXP`, as it does not support patterns with lookarounds.

Comment: What is the MySQL version? Are you sure the `\n` not a newline in your string?

Comment: In fact the \n is the result from different selections made in a checkbox group in a Joomla RSForm! Pro form and results in a newline in the sql field value. MySQL version 5.7.31

Comment: My query (Joomla) is   for($i=0;$i<($length+1);$i++){
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $db->setQuery("SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM #__rsform_submission_values WHERE `FormId` = '".JRequest::getInt('formId' )."' AND `FieldName` = 'plages' AND `FieldValue` REGEXP '".($i+1)."[[:>:]]')" );
.....

Comment: But the REGEXP will not be ok with results like 1\n12....looking for 2 will catch the 2 of 12

Comment: Sorry, I meant `(^|[^0-9])12($|[^0-9])`.

Comment: Does your regex engine support `\b` for word boundary? If so, maybe `\b12\b` would work? But only if the \n is a newline character, not a literal "\" followed by "n".

Comment: (^|[^0-9])12($|[^0-9]) WORKS... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `(?<![0-9])12(?![0-9])` works for you in an online regex engine, the following regex must work for you in `REGEXP` pattern that is POSIX based:

```sql
(^|[^0-9])12($|[^0-9])
```

Or, you may use word boundaries:

```
[[:<:]]12[[:>:]]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V9TVJp/4).

*Details*:

- `(^|[^0-9])` - start of string or a non-digit char
- `[[:<:]]` - leading word boundary
- `12` - a specific numeric value, `12` here
- `[[:>:]]` - trailing word boundary
- `($|[^0-9])` - end of string or a non-digit.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 8.0,

```
"\\b12\\b"
```

or

```
"\\s12\\s"
```

The former checks for "word boundaries" and might be better.  The latter checks for whitespace, such as `\n`.

The doubled backslashes may be overkill, depending on the client.